# Bind IP (GKE LoadBalancer IP) to Google Cloud Endpoint

Tags: ip, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I have a simple question but struggling on it (For a while now, following a lot of Google Tutorials tho..).

---

***Context:***

> I have a GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine) cluster which has workloads (Load Balancers, Pods, etc)
>
> I have a LoadBalancer for ServiceA which has an external IP XX.XXX.XXX.XX. This service is exposing port YYYY. I can then connect to my service using this IP:PORT combination.

---

**Problem:**
How can I access this `XX.XXX.XXX.XX:YYYY` from an address such as `<YOUR_NAMING>.endpoints.<PROJECT_ID>.cloud.goog`?

Possible example:

*We have a service running a gRPC server (:9000) and a REST API (:9001)*

- `service-a.endpoints.emixam23.cloud.goog`: (A request to this endpoint [HTTP] would forward it to `XX.XXX.XXX.XX:9001`, as well as a gRPC connection could be forwarded to `XX.XXX.XXX.XX:9000` depending on the configuration)
- `service-a.endpoints.emixam23.cloud.goog:9001`: (A request to this endpoint [HTTP] would forward it to `XX.XXX.XXX.XX:9001` and only)
- `service-a.endpoints.emixam23.cloud.goog:9000`: (A connection to this endpoint [gRPC] would be forwarded to `XX.XXX.XXX.XX:9000` and only)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not super clear on how the Google endpoints are configured but can say that you can configure a service type LoadBalancer t expose those two ports. As long as the endpoint can forward traffic to the LB IP:Port, this should work. What is the problem you are running into?

Comment: My issue is that I followed all their tutorial and it never works.. only one time I got something as a Swagger page but it’s not at all what I try to do. Do you have any WORKING solution to achieve it? Any helpful link? Thanks !

Comment: Could you specify which tutorial you followed and never work? I want test it in my end.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/get-started-kubernetes-engine was on of them, https://medium.com/google-cloud/exploring-grpc-on-google-cloud-platform-82531b4b82b7 also

Comment: Which step was you stuck in [cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/…](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/get-started-kubernetes-engine)? I tried it in my testing environment without issue.

Comment: Wow, but can you share the final proto file you have and the 2 yaml files you have 

Comment: I think he is using the ones from the guide he shared. I would say that you should try them and confirm if they work for you.